# Problems with links changing color when clicked

Tags: html

I am a newbie.
I'm trying to make an HTML page containing a series of links. I have to visit those links even in a non-sequential way, so I have to remember which ones are already visited and which ones are not.
I thought about changing the color of the link visited from time to time and I would like the color to remain so until the browser is closed. When the browser is reopened, all links should return to their original color.
This is the code I used (with help from stackoverflow), the colors work, but the site that all links open to me is always the last one, ie I click on google.com and apple.com opens instead. A help? Thank you.

```js
function openPortal(elem) {
    window.open("https://google.com");
    elem.style.color = "red ";
}

function openPortal(elem) {
    window.open("https://apple.com");
    elem.style.color = "red ";
}

if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "xqyfa64y"
    }], "*")
}
window.name = "result"

let allLines = []
window.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
    if (message.data.console) {
        let insert = document.querySelector("#insert")
        allLines.push(message.data.console.payload)
        insert.innerHTML = allLines.join(";\r")
        let result = eval.call(null, message.data.console.payload)
        if (result !== undefined) {
            console.log(result)
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<p class="pos_winmsg">
    <span style="cursor:pointer">
        <a id="winapp" onclick="openPortal( this )" style="font-size:100%">Google</a>
    </span>
</p>

<p class="pos_winmsg">
    <span style="cursor:pointer">
        <a id="winapp" onclick="openPortal( this )" style="font-size:100%">Apple</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

No matter, which of the links you click, it will always run this function:

```
function openPortal( elem ) {
    window.open("https://apple.com");
    elem.style.color="red ";
}
```

As you might be able to tell the `elem` (Element) which the function is called from doesn't actually have any influence on what page will be opened, as `window.open("https://apple.com")` is executed.

You should add an `href="https://google.com"` into the `<a>` tag belonging to the google link (do this for all links, not just google), so that you can in the function open the href given by the `elem` passed into the function:

```
function openPortal( elem ) {
    window.open(elem.href);
    elem.style.color="red ";
}
```

But if you add an href you don't actually need `window.open(elem.href);`, since the link would just open once from the href and once from the function. The function would  therefore look like this:

```
function openPortal( elem ) {
    elem.style.color="red ";
}
```

Edit: I just noticed, you have the `openPortal()` function defined twice. This would not work AND is unnecessary, since there's two functions with the same name, meaning only the later of the two matters. Also even if both were separate functions, there is only one function needed.

The entire code should look something like this:

```
<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>  
        <p class="pos_winmsg">
    <span style="cursor:pointer">
      <a id="winapp" href="https://google.com" onclick="openPortal( this )" style="font-size:100%">Google</a>
    </span></p>
    <script>
          function openPortal( elem ) {
            elem.style.color="red ";
          }
    </script>  
    <p class="pos_winmsg">
    <span style="cursor:pointer">
      <a id="winapp" href="https://apple.com" onclick="openPortal( this )" style="font-size:100%">Apple</a>
    </span></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[//]]></script>
    <script>
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "xqyfa64y"
      }], "*")
    }
    window.name = "result"
    </script>
    <script>
      let allLines = []
      window.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
        if (message.data.console){
          let insert = document.querySelector("#insert")
          allLines.push(message.data.console.payload)
          insert.innerHTML = allLines.join(";\r")    
          let result = eval.call(null, message.data.console.payload)
          if (result !== undefined){
            console.log(result)
          }
        }
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you but both google and apple are opened twice in two new tabs as I did <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" ...

Comment: Oh yes, since the link itself already has an href now, you don't actually need to do `window.open(elem.href);` anymore. I assumed you were aware. If you only want one tab using only an href is simpler., using `window.open(elem.href);` is just to show how you would access the href of the element passed into the function.

Comment: You are right, of course. Very nice now, thank you a lot!